# ubuntu 20.04:webcam video flickering issue in chrome only

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, video, skype, webcam

i have updated my ubuntu from 18.04 lts to 20.04 lts when i access my webcam in chrome using  this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webcam-test-test-your-web/onpahlllefmgleepfkdmneanjjpffmkh/related?hl=en) i can see my video is black and white and is flickering
i am using [janus video room plugin](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videoroomtest.html)
it shows the same behavior and other participant can see that flickering too
i have tested in firefox webcam is working fine there also tested on skype and ubuntu app called cheese its working fine
it looks like the issue is in chrome i am using chrome Version 86.0.4240.193 (Official Build) (64-bit)
can any one guide what is causing the issue ?

Comment: Usually, when I see Chrome issues on Linux, my first step is to suggest disabling hardware acceleration and then restarting the browser to make sure the changes take effect.